# RTC workflow with multiple streams?

Tags: rtc

I'm trying to find a sane way to handle multi-stream development. Thus far, our team members have created separate repository workspaces for each stream, and in turn have separate Eclipse workspaces to house those repository workspaces. Up to this point, this has provided us with the separation needed to work on different streams. My question is: is this the most efficient way to go about this? For example, consider a project with 2 streams: version 1.1 and version 2.0. These 2 streams are being worked on in parallel, and we need to bounce around between the two (in that, we need to deliver changes to both). How should we handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the most efficient way to go about this?

Yes, in that it is certainly more effective than creating one stream per developer ;)
The Stream is the public publication space.
The repo workspaces are the private (or scoped) publication spaces.

All collaboration goes mainly through the Stream.

> consider a project with 2 streams: version 1.1 and version 2.0. These 2 streams are being worked on in parallel, and we need to bounce around between the two

You can work on both through 2 different repo workspaces, each one referring in their flow target section their respective Stream.

The only difficulty is regarding the Eclipse Workspace, which has as an ID the project name, which means you cannot work on your Project `P2.0` (named "`P`") in the same *Eclipse* workspace if said workspace (which has nothing to do with an RTC repo or local workspace) already contains `P1.0` (named also "`P`").

In that case, it is safer to "switch Eclipse workspace" in order to access one project or the other project.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Less of an RTC thing and more of an Eclipse design feature. Thanks @VonC, I appreciate your help.